# field collection - taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I used taxonomy term field with field collection and taxonomy term id not attached on node id. taxonomy term cannot get result. look video! used D8 but in D7 have the same problem. the same problem have field collection like module, Paragraphs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEI1yDcJXT4

Comment: Check my answer on this question:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195737/field-collection-taxonomy-term-cant-display