# field collection - taxonomy term can't display

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I used taxonomy term with field collection and taxonomy term can't display 
look this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEI1yDcJXT4

Answer (score 0):

By default the taxonomy term page will list all content (NODES) that is referenced by this term. In your case you are referencing the field collection item by this term.

To display the nodes in the term page you need to create a new view as below:

1. Create a view of type content and add a relation to the field collection type.
2. In the view filters you need to add filters by content type and another filter to restrict the result by the taxonomy you are using.
3. Add a contextual filter that will filter the results by the term id - provide a default value from the URL, thus will ensure that you are displaying only nodes referenced by the term id you are viewing.

now you need to use page manager, context, custom code, etc... to place this view in the term page.

How it will work:
When you are viewing a term page it will display the view we previously created. this view will extract the term id from the URL and query nodes related to the term.

Comment: I tray it many times. but it is imosible or i don know how to do that. could you video tutorial how to do that??